# Gingerit vs PySpellChecker

Tags: python, grammar, lib, pyspellchecker

what's the difference between **Gingerit** and **pyspellchecker** and what are their advantages and disadvantages?

*Gingerit example:*

```
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt
text = "Hello world!"
corrected_text = GingerIt().parse(text)
print(corrected_text['result'])
```

*Pyspellchecker example:*

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
s = SpellChecker()
s.correction("Hello World!")
```

is there any difference between **gingerit** and **pyspellchecker**, what are the advantages/disadvantages between **gingerit** and **pyspellchecker**?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This question is far too broad for this site. SO is a question and answer site designed for _specific_ questions about specific code problems or errors. This question is likely to be closed as opinion-based, unless you can specify what you have tried, and a particular problem you have encountered with one of these packages based on your own research. There are plenty of general discussion forums online for this more general opinion question

Comment: then why is a post with **1000+ votes** of differences between lists and tuples...

Comment: my question about diffrences between **gingerit** and **pyspellchecker** and what library should i use for grammar correction app

Comment: "what library should i use for grammar correction app" Questions asking for recommendations for libraries are explicitly off topic at stack overflow, and "what should I choose" is entirely opinion-based, which is also off-topic. "differences between lists and tuples" is about python built-in types, not external libraries, and is not opinion-based. Have you tried each of the libraries in question? Have you tested them on corpuses of text with known grammar issues of the type you expect to encounter in production? Checked for performance differences between them?

Comment: thats the question, DIFFERENCES BETWEEN gingerit and pyspellchecker, theres also a post of differences between lists and tuples with 1000+ votes.,  and the question of "what library should i use" i already removed it tho...